# Toggle mute key to 25% instead of 0%

Tags: linux, audio

F6/Mute key toggles between the 0% and last volume such as 100% or 90%. Can this be changed so that the Mute goes to 25% instead of 0%?

> Linux blue 5.0.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 14:59:14 UTC
>   2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Toggling mute state for audio works independent to setting for audio level
mute is either on or off and has no option to reduce/restore level

Pulseaudio has optional [module-role-ducking](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index61h3) based on media.role property of pulseaudio streams.
By default, "music" and "video" streams are ducked, and "phone" streams trigger the ducking.